# Como concatenar js dentro de função php

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho essa class e função

```
class Controller {

  public function vazio($verfica) {
      if (empty($verfica)) {
          return 'Vazio';
      } else {
          return 'Ok';
      }
  }

}
```

Chamo essa função dentro do `append` e preciso concatenar a variavel dentro da função

```
divposts.append("<?php echo $ctlr->vazio("+val.valor+")?>");
```

Comment: Não tem como fazer isso porque o PHP é processado no servidor e o JS no navegador depois que o PHP já fez a sua parte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesse seu caso, como a sua função está dentro do seu ***controller*** responsável pelo seus ***requests*** e está você usando a arquitetura ***MVC***, o correto seria através do ***javascript*** você chamar essa função do seu ***controller***.

**Por exemplo:**

*Seu Javascript*

```
$.ajax({
  url: window.location.origin + '/sua-rota-apontada-para-controller',
  type: 'GET' // método http da sua rota
  dataType: 'application/json',
  success: function(data){
    divposts.append('<span>' + data + '</span>');
  },
  erro: function(err){
    console.log(err);  
  }
});
```